# Hide dynamically created menu on click anywhere on page jquery

Tags: jquery, events, dynamic, hide, event-propagation

I have some dynamically created menus on a page that need to hide whenever the user clicks anywhere on the page. This needs to work if the user clicks the menu, or tries to open another menu.

I also want the event handler to unbind itself when done hiding. I've found a solution using `document.on()` one `one()` but would really like to restrict the `document` handler to something further down the DOM. Problem is that it breaks my code.

Any help with an elegant solution appreciated.

The main reason I want to do this is to be able to prevent `event propagation` such as in:

[**Failing propagation DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QsggA/8/)

[**Succeeding propagation, failing `one()` clickhandler DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QsggA/9/)

**Javascript**

```
// I want to change "document" to ".menus" here
$(document).on("click", ".displayMenu", function(e)
{
    var $menu =  $(this).siblings(".menu");
    $(document).one("click", function(e2) 
       {
           if (e.target!=e2.target)
               $menu.hide(); 
       });
    $menu.toggle();
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="menus">
    <div>
        <div class="displayMenu">Show menu 1</div>
        <div class="menu">menu 1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="displayMenu">Show menu 2</div>
        <div class="menu">menu 2</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: I checked **Succeeding propagation, failing one() clickhandler DEMO** but could not find how one() is failing in that ??? can you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: Click one menu, then click the other. The first menu will not hide.

Comment: Just realized that `stopPropagation()` will prevent the `document.one()` event handler from triggering... Of course. *sigh* Thing is that even *without*  `stopPropagation()`, `document.one()` fails... Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @TapanC I realized I made an obvious mistake with `stopPropagation()`, of course it should prevent the `document.one()` event from triggering. I don't understand why `document.one()`  *still* doesn't run even without `stopPropagation()` but here's a working solution.

Not entirely elegant though (I don't like the global `hide()` command) so any better suggestions appreciated! :)

**[Working (unpretty) solution DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QsggA/10/)**

```
$(".menus").on("click", ".displayMenu", function(e)
{
    // Hide all
    $(".menu").hide();
    // Get current menu
    var $menu =  $(this).siblings(".menu").show();
    $(document).one("click", function(e2) 
       {
           if (e.target!=e2.target)
               $menu.hide(); 
       });
    // Prevent propagation
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```